# Can an axon recieve signal from other neuron or axon of other neuron?

Tags: neurology, neuron

As there is a very complex network of neurons in our brain so could it happen that an axon can recieves a signal from another parallel axon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed synapses called [axo-axonic or axo-axonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axo-axonic_synapse) that involve a synapse directly onto an axon from another axon.

There's quite a variety to these, so it's difficult to make any generalizable statements about them as a group besides the tautological fact that they involve a synapse from an axon onto an axon; like other types of synapse you'd want to first specify a brain region and source/target neuron type to start looking at their properties and likely network effects.